# Creating an instance of SelectionChangedEventArgs in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a user control which is having a listview inside it. The SelectionChanged event of this list view is handled inside the user control. The code for the same is as follows:

```
        private void lstvMyView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {...}
```

I want to call this handler again from some other place inside the user control. So to call this handler i need the "SelectionChangedEventArgs" there. When I am trying to create the instance of "SelectionChangedEventArgs", i am unable to understand what should I pass as parameters to the constructor of "SelectionChangedEventArgs".

The place from where I am suppose to call this handler does not add or remove any items in the listview. It just navigates in the items in the listview thereby changing the selectedindex of the listview.

I am trying to do something like this. The below code is obviously incorrect.

```
lstvMyView_SelectionChanged(_lstvMyView, new SelectionChangedEventArgs());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to call this handler again from some other place inside the user control

**Don't**. An event handler is not supposed to be called explicitly from your code. Whatever you're doing in this handler, you can put it in another method that only takes the parameters it needs, and call `that` method from your code.

Comment: Hmm... But what if the code in the handler is using e in it? Thomas, just 1 more request, I have added a question in this forum but not able to find any answers, can you please look into it for me..!!! The link is as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777683/unable-to-set-focus-to-datepicker-using-attached-property-in-wpf

Comment: Does it really need the `e` parameter ? It probably only needs *some* of its properties... Just pass those to your method

Comment: This sounds like a good work around. Will try this out! Thanks for your time..!! :) Thomas, did you try out the other problem I had?? Please do check it out as I am really wanna make that working..!!

Comment: I am unit testing some code and want to instantiate a SelectionChangedEventArgs object for testing purposes (to send to a combo box's OnSelectionChanged method.  Being told not to sort of leaves me hanging here.

Comment: @JasonFuerstenberg, I'm not saying you shouldn't instantiate a SelectionChangedEventArgs; I'm just saying you shouldn't call an event handler directly.

Comment: This answer is just silly. Controls have to raise events. If a control raises an event that takes SelectionChangedEventArgs as an argument to the constructor for the EventArgs, we need to be able to construct an instance of SelectionChangedEventArgs. The object needs to be constructed somewhere. If it's not being passed down by some other event, we need to be able to construct the object.

Answer (score 2):

The `SelectionChangedEventArgs` can be instantiated for unit testing as follows:

```
new SelectionChangedEventArgs(
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChangedEvent, 
    new List<CustomViewModel> { }, 
    new List<CustomViewModel> { customViewModel }
)
```

Beware that both the `removedItems` and `addedItems` cannot be null so an empty collection should be passed.